# CategoryFilter as column selector

Tags: javascript, php, html, charts, google-visualization

I used the following example to create a drop down menu: https://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/WaUu2/ which makes it possible to select a column and then show the line on the graph.

But I also want to use a ChartRangeFilter but the problem is this method doesn't use a dashboard so I have no clue were to start to make everything work together. And most of the examples I found use this dashboard method.

I want it to approximately to be like this example  http://jsfiddle.net/x7pyk55q/4/ but would like to keep filtering on the columns.

It would be nice if someone could provide me an example how to do it the right way. I'm a bit new when it comes to this.

My code:

```
<html>
  <head>
   <title>Temperature Chart</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="graph.css">
    <!--Load the Ajax API-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
    google.load('visualization', '1.1', {'packages':['controls','corechart']});
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <!--this is the div that will hold the pie chart-->
    <div id="colFilter_div"></div>
    <div id="chart_div"></div>

    <script language="JavaScript">
      // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      function drawChart() {
      // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
      var jsonData = "{\"cols\":[{\"id\":\"\",\"label\":\"datetime\",\"type\":\"datetime\"},{\"id\":\"\",\"label\":\"RPI1\",\"type\":\"number\"},{\"id\":\"\",\"label\":\"RPI2\",\"type\":\"number\"}],\"rows\":[{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Date(2017, 0, 3, 15, 40, 41)\"},{\"v\":\"22\"},{\"v\":null}]},{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Date(2017, 0, 3, 15, 40, 52)\"},{\"v\":\"21\"},{\"v\":null}]},{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Date(2017, 0, 3, 15, 41, 2)\"},{\"v\":\"22\"},{\"v\":null}]},{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Date(2017, 0, 3, 15, 41, 12)\"},{\"v\":\"20\"},{\"v\":null}]},{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Date(2017, 0, 3, 15, 41, 22)\"},{\"v\":\"21\"},{\"v\":null}]},{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Date(2017, 0, 3, 15, 41, 32)\"},{\"v\":\"21\"},{\"v\":null}]},{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Date(2017, 0, 3, 15, 41, 43)\"},{\"v\":\"21\"},{\"v\":null}]},{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Date(2017, 0, 3, 15, 41, 53)\"},{\"v\":\"20\"},{\"v\":null}]},{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Date(2017, 0, 3, 15, 42, 3)\"},{\"v\":\"21\"},{\"v\":null}]},{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Date(2017, 0, 3, 15, 42, 13)\"},{\"v\":\"22\"},{\"v\":null}]},{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Date(2017, 0, 3, 15, 42, 23)\"},{\"v\":\"21\"},{\"v\":null}]},{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Date(2017, 0, 3, 15, 42, 34)\"},{\"v\":\"21\"},{\"v\":null}]},{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Date(2017, 0, 3, 15, 42, 44)\"},{\"v\":\"20\"},{\"v\":null}]},{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Date(2017, 0, 3, 15, 42, 54)\"},{\"v\":\"19\"},{\"v\":null}]},{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Date(2017, 0, 3, 15, 43, 4)\"},{\"v\":\"20\"},{\"v\":null}]},{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Date(2017, 0, 3, 15, 43, 15)\"},{\"v\":\"22\"},{\"v\":null}]},{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Date(2017, 0, 3, 15, 43, 25)\"},{\"v\":\"20\"},{\"v\":null}]},{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Date(2017, 0, 3, 15, 43, 35)\"},{\"v\":\"20\"},{\"v\":null}]},{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Date(2017, 0, 3, 15, 43, 45)\"},{\"v\":\"20\"},{\"v\":null}]},{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Date(2017, 0, 3, 15, 43, 55)\"},{\"v\":\"20\"},{\"v\":null}]},{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Date(2017, 0, 3, 15, 44, 6)\"},{\"v\":\"20\"},{\"v\":null}]},{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Date(2017, 0, 3, 15, 44, 16)\"},{\"v\":\"19\"},{\"v\":null}]},{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Date(2017, 0, 3, 15, 44, 26)\"},{\"v\":\"20\"},{\"v\":null}]},{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Date(2017, 0, 3, 15, 44, 36)\"},{\"v\":\"20\"},{\"v\":null}]},{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Date(2017, 0, 3, 15, 44, 47)\"},{\"v\":\"20\"},{\"v\":null}]},{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Date(2017, 0, 3, 15, 44, 57)\"},{\"v\":\"20\"},{\"v\":null}]},{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Date(2017, 0, 3, 15, 45, 7)\"},{\"v\":\"19\"},{\"v\":null}]},{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Date(2017, 0, 3, 15, 45, 17)\"},{\"v\":\"20\"},{\"v\":null}]},{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Date(2017, 0, 3, 15, 45, 27)\"},{\"v\":\"21\"},{\"v\":null}]},{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Date(2017, 0, 3, 15, 45, 38)\"},{\"v\":\"21\"},{\"v\":null}]},{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Date(2017, 0, 3, 15, 45, 48)\"},{\"v\":\"21\"},{\"v\":null}]},{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Date(2017, 0, 3, 15, 45, 58)\"},{\"v\":\"23\"},{\"v\":null}]},{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Date(2017, 0, 3, 15, 46, 8)\"},{\"v\":\"23\"},{\"v\":null}]},{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Date(2017, 0, 3, 15, 46, 18)\"},{\"v\":null},{\"v\":\"24\"}]},{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Date(2017, 0, 3, 15, 46, 29)\"},{\"v\":null},{\"v\":\"22\"}]},{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Date(2017, 0, 3, 15, 46, 39)\"},{\"v\":null},{\"v\":\"22\"}]},{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Date(2017, 0, 3, 15, 46, 49)\"},{\"v\":null},{\"v\":\"21\"}]},{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Date(2017, 0, 3, 15, 46, 59)\"},{\"v\":null},{\"v\":\"21\"}]},{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Date(2017, 0, 3, 15, 47, 10)\"},{\"v\":null},{\"v\":\"22\"}]},{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Date(2017, 0, 3, 15, 47, 20)\"},{\"v\":null},{\"v\":\"21\"}]},{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Date(2017, 0, 3, 15, 47, 30)\"},{\"v\":null},{\"v\":\"21\"}]},{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Date(2017, 0, 3, 15, 47, 40)\"},{\"v\":null},{\"v\":\"22\"}]}]}"
      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(JSON.parse(jsonData));
      // return the JSON data in console
      console.log(JSON.stringify(data));


      var columnsTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      columnsTable.addColumn('number', 'colIndex');
      columnsTable.addColumn('string', 'colLabel');
      var initState= {selectedValues: []};
      // put the columns into this data table (skip column 0)
      for (var i = 1; i < data.getNumberOfColumns(); i++) {
        columnsTable.addRow([i, data.getColumnLabel(i)]);
      }
      initState.selectedValues.push(data.getColumnLabel(1));

      var chart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
        chartType: 'LineChart',
        containerId: 'chart_div',
        dataTable: data,
        options: {
            title: 'Temps',
            width: 1600,
            height: 600,
            hAxis:{
                title:'DateTime'
            },
            vAxis:{
                title: 'Temperature',
            }
         }
      });

      var columnFilter = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
        controlType: 'CategoryFilter',
        containerId: 'colFilter_div',
        dataTable: columnsTable,
        options: {
            filterColumnLabel: 'colLabel',
            ui: {
                label:'',
                caption: 'Select RPI',
                allowTyping: false,
                allowMultiple: true,
                allowNone: false,
                selectedValuesLayout: 'aside'
             }
         },
         state: initState
      });

      function setChartView () {
        var state = columnFilter.getState();
        var row;
        var view = {
            columns: [0]
        };
        for (var i = 0; i < state.selectedValues.length; i++) {
            row = columnsTable.getFilteredRows([{column: 1, value: state.selectedValues[i]}])[0];
            view.columns.push(columnsTable.getValue(row, 0));
        }
        // sort the indices into their original order
        view.columns.sort(function (a, b) {
            return (a - b);
        });
        chart.setView(view);
        chart.draw();
    }
      google.visualization.events.addListener(columnFilter, 'statechange', setChartView);

      setChartView();
      columnFilter.draw();  
    }

      </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the *ChartRangeFilter* to set the `view.rows`

similar to how the *CategoryFilter* sets the `view.columns`

when the `'statechange'` event fires on the *ChartRangeFilter*,

use it's `state` to filter the rows for the range selected,

then redraw the chart

---

the *ChartRangeFilter* should be drawn using the same data and view as the chart

and re-drawn when the *CategoryFilter* changes

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawChart,
  packages:['controls','corechart']
});

function drawChart() {
  // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
  var jsonData = "{\"cols\":[{\"id\":\"\",\"label\":\"datetime\",\"type\":\"datetime\"},{\"id\":\"\",\"label\":\"RPI1\",\"type\":\"number\"},{\"id\":\"\",\"label\":\"RPI2\",\"type\":\"number\"}],\"rows\":[{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Date(2017, 0, 3, 15, 40, 41)\"},{\"v\":\"22\"},{\"v\":null}]},{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Date(2017, 0, 3, 15, 40, 52)\"},{\"v\":\"21\"},{\"v\":null}]},{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Date(2017, 0, 3, 15, 41, 2)\"},{\"v\":\"22\"},{\"v\":null}]},{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Date(2017, 0, 3, 15, 41, 12)\"},{\"v\":\"20\"},{\"v\":null}]},{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Date(2017, 0, 3, 15, 41, 22)\"},{\"v\":\"21\"},{\"v\":null}]},{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Date(2017, 0, 3, 15, 41, 32)\"},{\"v\":\"21\"},{\"v\":null}]},{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Date(2017, 0, 3, 15, 41, 43)\"},{\"v\":\"21\"},{\"v\":null}]},{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Date(2017, 0, 3, 15, 41, 53)\"},{\"v\":\"20\"},{\"v\":null}]},{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Date(2017, 0, 3, 15, 42, 3)\"},{\"v\":\"21\"},{\"v\":null}]},{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Date(2017, 0, 3, 15, 42, 13)\"},{\"v\":\"22\"},{\"v\":null}]},{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Date(2017, 0, 3, 15, 42, 23)\"},{\"v\":\"21\"},{\"v\":null}]},{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Date(2017, 0, 3, 15, 42, 34)\"},{\"v\":\"21\"},{\"v\":null}]},{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Date(2017, 0, 3, 15, 42, 44)\"},{\"v\":\"20\"},{\"v\":null}]},{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Date(2017, 0, 3, 15, 42, 54)\"},{\"v\":\"19\"},{\"v\":null}]},{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Date(2017, 0, 3, 15, 43, 4)\"},{\"v\":\"20\"},{\"v\":null}]},{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Date(2017, 0, 3, 15, 43, 15)\"},{\"v\":\"22\"},{\"v\":null}]},{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Date(2017, 0, 3, 15, 43, 25)\"},{\"v\":\"20\"},{\"v\":null}]},{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Date(2017, 0, 3, 15, 43, 35)\"},{\"v\":\"20\"},{\"v\":null}]},{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Date(2017, 0, 3, 15, 43, 45)\"},{\"v\":\"20\"},{\"v\":null}]},{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Date(2017, 0, 3, 15, 43, 55)\"},{\"v\":\"20\"},{\"v\":null}]},{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Date(2017, 0, 3, 15, 44, 6)\"},{\"v\":\"20\"},{\"v\":null}]},{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Date(2017, 0, 3, 15, 44, 16)\"},{\"v\":\"19\"},{\"v\":null}]},{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Date(2017, 0, 3, 15, 44, 26)\"},{\"v\":\"20\"},{\"v\":null}]},{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Date(2017, 0, 3, 15, 44, 36)\"},{\"v\":\"20\"},{\"v\":null}]},{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Date(2017, 0, 3, 15, 44, 47)\"},{\"v\":\"20\"},{\"v\":null}]},{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Date(2017, 0, 3, 15, 44, 57)\"},{\"v\":\"20\"},{\"v\":null}]},{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Date(2017, 0, 3, 15, 45, 7)\"},{\"v\":\"19\"},{\"v\":null}]},{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Date(2017, 0, 3, 15, 45, 17)\"},{\"v\":\"20\"},{\"v\":null}]},{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Date(2017, 0, 3, 15, 45, 27)\"},{\"v\":\"21\"},{\"v\":null}]},{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Date(2017, 0, 3, 15, 45, 38)\"},{\"v\":\"21\"},{\"v\":null}]},{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Date(2017, 0, 3, 15, 45, 48)\"},{\"v\":\"21\"},{\"v\":null}]},{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Date(2017, 0, 3, 15, 45, 58)\"},{\"v\":\"23\"},{\"v\":null}]},{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Date(2017, 0, 3, 15, 46, 8)\"},{\"v\":\"23\"},{\"v\":null}]},{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Date(2017, 0, 3, 15, 46, 18)\"},{\"v\":null},{\"v\":\"24\"}]},{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Date(2017, 0, 3, 15, 46, 29)\"},{\"v\":null},{\"v\":\"22\"}]},{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Date(2017, 0, 3, 15, 46, 39)\"},{\"v\":null},{\"v\":\"22\"}]},{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Date(2017, 0, 3, 15, 46, 49)\"},{\"v\":null},{\"v\":\"21\"}]},{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Date(2017, 0, 3, 15, 46, 59)\"},{\"v\":null},{\"v\":\"21\"}]},{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Date(2017, 0, 3, 15, 47, 10)\"},{\"v\":null},{\"v\":\"22\"}]},{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Date(2017, 0, 3, 15, 47, 20)\"},{\"v\":null},{\"v\":\"21\"}]},{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Date(2017, 0, 3, 15, 47, 30)\"},{\"v\":null},{\"v\":\"21\"}]},{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Date(2017, 0, 3, 15, 47, 40)\"},{\"v\":null},{\"v\":\"22\"}]}]}"
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(JSON.parse(jsonData));

  var columnsTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  columnsTable.addColumn('number', 'colIndex');
  columnsTable.addColumn('string', 'colLabel');
  var initState= {selectedValues: []};
  // put the columns into this data table (skip column 0)
  for (var i = 1; i < data.getNumberOfColumns(); i++) {
    columnsTable.addRow([i, data.getColumnLabel(i)]);
  }
  initState.selectedValues.push(data.getColumnLabel(1));

  var chart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    chartType: 'LineChart',
    containerId: 'chart_div',
    dataTable: data,
    options: {
        title: 'Temps',
        width: 1600,
        height: 600,
        hAxis:{
            title:'DateTime'
        },
        vAxis:{
            title: 'Temperature',
        }
     }
  });

  var rangeFilter = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
    controlType: 'ChartRangeFilter',
    containerId: 'rngFilter_div',
    dataTable: data,
    options: {
      filterColumnIndex: 0,
      ui: {
        chartOptions: {
          width: 1600,
          height: 200,
          hAxis:{
              title:'DateTime'
          },
          vAxis:{
              title: 'Temperature'
          }
        }
      }
    }
  });

  var columnFilter = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
    controlType: 'CategoryFilter',
    containerId: 'colFilter_div',
    dataTable: columnsTable,
    options: {
        filterColumnLabel: 'colLabel',
        ui: {
            label:'',
            caption: 'Select RPI',
            allowTyping: false,
            allowMultiple: true,
            allowNone: false,
            selectedValuesLayout: 'aside'
         }
     },
     state: initState
  });

  function setChartViewCols () {
    var state = columnFilter.getState();
    var row;
    var view = {
        columns: [0]
    };
    for (var i = 0; i < state.selectedValues.length; i++) {
        row = columnsTable.getFilteredRows([{column: 1, value: state.selectedValues[i]}])[0];
        view.columns.push(columnsTable.getValue(row, 0));
    }
    // sort the indices into their original order
    view.columns.sort(function (a, b) {
        return (a - b);
    });
    view.rows = null;
    chart.setView(view);
    chart.draw();
    rangeFilter.setView(view);
    rangeFilter.setState();
    rangeFilter.draw();
  }
  google.visualization.events.addListener(columnFilter, 'statechange', setChartViewCols);

  function setChartViewRows () {
    var state = rangeFilter.getState();
    var view = chart.getView();
    view.rows = rangeFilter.getDataTable().getFilteredRows([{
      column: 0,
      minValue: state.range.start,
      maxValue: state.range.end
    }]);
    chart.setView(view);
    chart.draw();
  }
  google.visualization.events.addListener(rangeFilter, 'statechange', setChartViewRows);

  setChartViewCols();
  columnFilter.draw();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="colFilter_div"></div>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
<div id="rngFilter_div"></div>
```

---

**note:**

recommend using `loader.js` to load the library, instead of `jsapi`

according to the [release notes](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/release_notes)...

> The version of Google Charts that remains available via the jsapi loader is no longer being updated consistently. Please use the new gstatic loader from now on.

`<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>`

this will *only* change the `load` statement

`google.charts.load('current', {packages:['controls','corechart']});`

you can also include the `callback` in the `load` statement, as in the above snippet...

Comment: Thank you for your time, this is what I was looking for!

Comment: Do you also know how I can make this chart responsive? I tried the following but it doesn't work properly $(window).resize(function(){
  drawChart();
});

Comment: that should work, if you remove the option for `width: 1600` -- would not affect `height`

Comment: Yes I did that already, it resizes but if I for example select RPI2 and then resize the chart. It forgets the selection and just resets. I guess that's because it just re-reruns the drawChart function. Is there a way to remember the chosen options when resizing?

Comment: Found it! The following solution works:                                              function resize() {
    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    setChartViewCols();
    columnFilter.draw(); 
  }
  window.onload = resize();
  window.onresize = resize;