# Google line chart CategoryFilter

Tags: filter, google-visualization, linechart

I'm attempting to display a control wrapper for a line chart. As of now, I can render the chart as seen in the screenshot.

[image]

Here's the function that generates this linechart

```
  function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([          
             [month, Hopong, Kalaw, Loilen],
             ["2018-09", 0, 0, 0],
             ["2018-11", 0, 0, 0],
             ["2018-12", 0.2, 0.3, 0.4],
             ["2019-01", 4, 5, 6]]);

          var dataTable = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(mainArray);
               var options = {
                   title: 'Pentration Rate',
                   curveType: 'function',
                   legend: { position: 'bottom' },
                    vAxis: {
                        viewWindow: {
                            min: 0
                        }
                    }
               };
              var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('pentration_chart'));

              chart.draw(dataTable, options)
  }
```

How do I create a ControlWrapper (dropdown) containing a list of townships eg: Hopong, Kalaw,Loilen etc, to filter by the township for penetration rate values for each month for a particular township.

Comment: @WhiteHat Added the code

Comment: the code you need can be found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41450579/5090771)...